# exporting eps figures maintaining the same size

Tags: graphics, export

I need to export some (2D) graphs from mathematica in eps format (only, unfortunately). The graphs are of similar nature (plotted from our different functions), and I have used the `PlotRange` option to make all the graphs of equal size (in both `x` and `y` direction). However, while exporting, we get the exported files of slightly unequal size. This creates a problem while putting in some document, as when we scale it to the same size, the font size looks different (which, needless to say are same for everyone). I tried to use the `ImageSize` option, but definitely I am making some mistakes, as I am not getting the graphics ( or to be precise  getting a small part of the graphics). So my question is, what is the best way to export all of them in a fixed size, say of 5cm x 4cm?

I use version 7. Advanced thanks for any help.

Comment: I think the answer is also `ImageSize`: `Export["test.eps", Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 200]]`

Comment: and I forgot to say you can specify e.g. `Imagesize->{250,200}`

Comment: @chris `ImageSize->{GoldenRatio*200,200}` or any size in agreement with the `AspectRatio` specification might be even better to avoid the useless white border around the graph.

Comment: You wrote that you tried `ImageSize` and you use the same `PlotRange`. What can still change the appearance of the plots are different Labels on the Axes/Frame (since `ImageSize` is the size of the whole Plot not just the plot area).
Also let me add this: If you want the picture to be 5cm wide the right `ImageSize` to use should be 5*72/2.54. Then you can set up the font size to whatever size you want (e.g. 10pt) and use the graphic without scaling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarize all contributions,

```
Export["test.eps", Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 1},ImageSize -> 5*72/2.54*{GoldenRatio,1},
BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 10, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}]]
```

should produce a magnificent postscript file of the right size ;-)

[image: it is truly magnificent]

Comment: you can also add: `BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 10, FontFamily -> "Helvetica"}` to get a sans-serif font in a size that matches the rest of your document.

Comment: This method no longer appears to work (using version 12.3).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if something happened between Mathematica version 7 and Mathematica version 12.3, but the accepted answer does not work for me.

```
Export[FileNameJoin[{"test.eps"}], 
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, ImageSize -> 5*72], ImageSize -> 5*72]
```

Results in an image that is only 3.597 in. wide as identified by Inkscape. Doing the same with the ".svg" extension results in a file of the appropriate dimensions. Trying to rescale the dimensions by multiplying the `ImageSize` option by a factor of 1.39 resulted in a image that was 5.013 inches wide- slightly more than the desired 5.00 inches.

I think the most reliable method to obtain an accurately sized .eps file is to save it as an .svg, open it in another editor (Inkscape) and save it as .eps.

EDIT: I checked the output after saving as .eps in Inkscape, and the size did not stay constant upon saving. As far as I can see, there's no efficient way to accomplish this.